# How to randomly pick an object from a collection?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am working on a modal that paints objects & then drops them using rigid body.
I'd like to include support for collections, where the user can store a group of objects as a collection & then randomly choose one of those objects to paint.

how can I access objects in a collection & duplicate the chosen object?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
import bpy
from random import random

#select your collection by name (in this case the collection named "Collection")
col = bpy.data.collections["Collection"]

objNum = len(col.objects)

#Generate random number 
randomIndex = round(random()*(objNum-1))  
#use the random number to call a random object in the collection
obj = col.objects[randomIndex]

#creat a copy of the object and link it to the collection 
newObj = obj.copy()
col.objects.link(newObj)
```

Comment: You may also want to `.copy()` the object's `.data`.

Comment: You can also use `random.randint(0,objNum - 1)`.

Comment: Since I am using a hit raycast, can I duplicate all objects & assign locations to equal the hit value?

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out right now.

Comment: @Animationsvfx you have to give us a lot more details to understand what you need

Comment: @rjg I noticed the object didnt duplicate, does copying the .data do that?

Comment: @Tareyes I will post the script later, let me try to set it up & put notes so you guys know what each part does.

Comment: @Animationsvfx copying the .data means copying the data block of the objects (if you don't copy it, the changes made to the original object will affect the copied object as well, but the actual object duplcation is done by the obj.copy).

And yes, you might have to change something, depending on your project